# Mask a view in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, mask

In **ActionScript 3** we can apply a mask of to a visual object like this:

```
SomeVisualObject.mask = maskShapeObject;
```

How can I achieve similar result in **Objective-C**? Assume I have two `UIImageView` objects, I want something like this:

```
imageView1.mask = imageView2;
```

How can I use one `UIImageView` to mask, or clip the shape of, another?

Comment: Read up on the compositing operations available when drawing UIImage objects.  Sounds like you want the "source over" mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mask UIViews in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559743/how-to-mask-uiviews-in-ios)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
 UIImage *maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"maskImage.png"];
maskLayer.contents = (id)maskImage.CGImage;
maskLayer.bounds = (CGRect){CGPointZero, maskImage.size};

UIImageView *imageViewToMask = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
imageViewToMask.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
imageViewToMask.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: It nearly works, but it seems like the mask has been positioned to the top left of the image, at location (-halfmaskwidth, -halfmaskheight).

Comment: ... turns out it works for me with `frame`, not with `bounds`.

Comment: @DanyalAytekin =) HTH