# Expanding circle animated transition between view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I have created a custom animated transitioning using a transition delegate:

```
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
vc.transitioningDelegate = self.transitioningDelegate;
```

The transitioning delegate is working perfectly, but I am trying to achieve an effect that I have not succeeded in doing thus far.
I am trying to make the new view controller appear like this effect:

[Cool animated tranisitoning](http://i.giflike.com/EJbsvev.gif)

I tried doing CGAffineTransformMakeScale, but it zooms the new view controller view, rather than just "expanding the circle of view into it". When trying to change with animations the bound and frame, it always fits the circle in the end with the screen bounds, and doesn't completely open up the circle like in the animation I gave.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This is just a guess, but you may try using a png as a mask (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559743/how-to-mask-uiviews-in-ios) then maybe animating the mask?

Comment: Thanks @leparlon, but will it be possible also if the view controller I'm transitioning to doesn't always look the same?

Comment: yes, that's possible with a mask layer. since it only defines which part of your destination view controller will be visible, it works with any view controller regardless how they look.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My first answer to this question was a modified version of an app I made a while ago, and would not be the best way to do it now (iOS 7 and beyond). In iOS 7 we can create custom transitions using the UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate and associated delegates and classes. This version encapsulates all the mask creation and resizing in the animator object (the one that conforms to UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning), so it keeps the controller code simpler allowing you to use any controller as the destination controller with no special code. Here is the code I use in the class that's doing the presentation,

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "RDPresentationAnimator.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate>
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)presentSecondController:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.button = sender;
    SecondViewController *second = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
    second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
    second.transitioningDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    RDPresentationAnimator *animator = [RDPresentationAnimator new];
    animator.isPresenting = YES;
    animator.senderFrame = self.button.frame;
    return animator;
}


-(id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed {
    NSLog(@"dismissed delegate called");
    RDPresentationAnimator *animator = [RDPresentationAnimator new];
    animator.isPresenting = NO;
    animator.senderFrame = self.button.frame;
    return animator;
}
```

Here's the code in the animator object. The .h,

```
@interface RDPresentationAnimator : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isPresenting;
@property (nonatomic) CGRect senderFrame;
```

And here's the .m,

```
@interface RDPresentationAnimator ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIBezierPath *maskPath;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIViewController *toVC;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIViewController *fromVC;
//@property (strong,nonatomic) id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning> transitionContext;
@end

    @implementation RDPresentationAnimator

    #define ANIMATION_TIME 0.6



    - (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
        return ANIMATION_TIME;
    }


    - (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
       // self.transitionContext = transitionContext;
        self.fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
        self.toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

        if (self.isPresenting) {
            [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:self.fromVC.view];
            [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:self.toVC.view];

            self.maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.senderFrame];
            CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
            maskLayer.frame = self.toVC.view.frame;
            maskLayer.path = self.maskPath.CGPath;
            self.toVC.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;

            UIBezierPath *newPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(-self.toVC.view.frame.size.width/2, -self.toVC.view.frame.size.height/2, self.toVC.view.frame.size.height*2, self.toVC.view.frame.size.height*2)];
            CABasicAnimation* pathAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"path"];
            //pathAnim.delegate = self;
            pathAnim.fromValue = (id)self.maskPath.CGPath;
            pathAnim.toValue = (id)newPath.CGPath;
            pathAnim.duration = ANIMATION_TIME;
            maskLayer.path = newPath.CGPath;
            [maskLayer addAnimation:pathAnim forKey:@"path"];
        }else{
            [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:self.toVC.view];
            [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:self.fromVC.view];
            self.maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(-self.fromVC.view.frame.size.width/2, -self.fromVC.view.frame.size.height/2, self.fromVC.view.frame.size.height*2, self.fromVC.view.frame.size.height*2)];
            CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
            maskLayer.frame = self.fromVC.view.frame;
            maskLayer.path = self.maskPath.CGPath;
            self.fromVC.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;

            UIBezierPath *newPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.senderFrame];
            CABasicAnimation* pathAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"path"];
            //pathAnim.delegate = self;
            pathAnim.fromValue = (id)self.maskPath.CGPath;
            pathAnim.toValue = (id)newPath.CGPath;
            pathAnim.duration = ANIMATION_TIME;
            maskLayer.path = newPath.CGPath;
            [maskLayer addAnimation:pathAnim forKey:@"path"];
        }

        [self performSelector:@selector(finishTransition:) withObject:transitionContext afterDelay:ANIMATION_TIME];
    }



    -(void)finishTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    }


    //- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag {
    //    NSLog(@"In didStop");
    //    if (flag) {
    //        if (self.isPresenting) {
    //            self.toVC.view.layer.mask = nil;
    //            [self.transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    //        }else{
    //            self.fromVC.view.layer.mask = nil;
    //            [self.transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    //            self.transitionContext = nil;
    //        }
    //    }
    //}


    -(void)dealloc {
        NSLog(@"In animator dealloc");
    }
```

This code also has the reverse animation for when you dismiss the modal controller (you only need to call dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: like normal in that class).

Comment: @Yarneo After doing some experimenting with the code I posted, I found that there was some sort of retain cycle that caused the animator and the presented controller to never get deallocated. I've  edited my code to fix that problem. I show all the lines I got rid of commented out. I no longer use a property for the transitionContext, or a delegate for pathAnim. Instead, I call completeTransition in a method called with a delay, that's based on the animation time.

Comment: thanks for the sample it works fine. i would edit the answer because in the container view you add for every step fromVC and toVC, it makes a problem because the container is release after the completion, i removed the addSubview, only this is necessary  [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:self.toVC.view]; and it fix the black screen on dismiss.

Comment: but the circle covers right side first and the covers left side

Answer (score 3):

I've made something like that in the past, but it doesn't have that expanding orange ring. My InitialViewController has a button added in the storyboard that has a round mask and a background image. The view controller I present has a mask whose size and position is set by passing in the frame of the button in InitialViewController that triggers the presentation. The presented view controller defines a protocol whose one method is invoked at the end of the animation. Here's the code in the initial view controller,

```
#import "InitialViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface InitialViewController () <ExpandingViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation InitialViewController


-(IBAction)expandToDetail:(UIButton *)sender { 
    ViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC"];
    vc.delegate = self;
    vc.buttonRect = sender.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
}


-(void)viewFinishedAnimating:(UIViewController *) sender { // delegate method from the presentedViewController
    [sender.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self presentViewController:sender animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Here's the code in the presented view controller, which performs the mask expansion. The .h file,

```
@protocol ExpandingViewDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)viewFinishedAnimating:(UIViewController *) sender;
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) CGRect buttonRect;
@property (weak,nonatomic) id<ExpandingViewDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

The .m file,

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIBezierPath *maskPath;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.buttonRect];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer.frame = self.view.frame;
    maskLayer.path = self.maskPath.CGPath;
    self.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    [self enlargeMask:maskLayer];
}

-(void)enlargeMask:(CAShapeLayer *) shapeLayer {

    UIBezierPath *newPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width/2, -self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.size.height*2, self.view.frame.size.height*2)];
    CABasicAnimation* pathAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"path"];
    pathAnim.delegate = self;
    pathAnim.fromValue = (id)self.maskPath.CGPath;
    pathAnim.toValue = (id)newPath.CGPath;
    pathAnim.duration = 6;
    shapeLayer.path = newPath.CGPath;
    [shapeLayer addAnimation:pathAnim forKey:@"path"];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag {
    if (flag) {
        self.view.layer.mask = nil;
        [self.delegate viewFinishedAnimating:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Only one thing, I noticed that once the delegate function is called and then the presentviewcontroller method is called, my screen freezes, and I cannot interact with it anymore. On the other hand, if I don't call presentviewcontroller, the screen is able to receive taps for scrolling and such, but any button that I press, it straight away crashes. Any idea why the screen freezes due to that?

Comment: @Yarneo, no, I don't know why that would happen. Are you sure you implemented the code exactly as I wrote it, because I've tested this, and it works with no freezing.

Comment: Copied it exactly as is. Been noticing there has been non stop allocations of [uiviewcontroller nextresponder], think its somehow connected.

Comment: @Yarneo, what do you have setup in the storyboard?

Comment: well, my initial view controller and the view controller I'm presenting have both an embedded view controller in them. this embedded view controller also has an embedded view controller itself, with custom segues connecting it to 3 different view controllers. It may be the case that the embedded view controllers will have already been initialised when i added the view, and then allocated again when calling the presentviewcontroller?

Comment: @Yarneo, the embedded view controllers shouldn't be initialized until their parent controller is, so I don't think they'll get initialized twice. Do you have a segue between the initial controller and the one you're presenting (you shouldn't, I'm just checking)?

Comment: I don't :( This is very weird. I will have to try it with clean view controllers and see what the culprit is. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ok. I found the source of the problem, very odd. For some reason, the view controllers themselves, once stripped from all of their embedded VCs, and basically everything, still had the same issue. However, once I made my initialviewcontroller the actual "is initial view controller", it worked. If I have another view controller before him, presenting him, then this issue occurs. Have no idea why though.

Comment: @Yarneo, I see the same thing if I add another controller before InitialViewController. I'm working on tracking down the error now.

Comment: @Yarneo, I'm baffled as to why we get this error if the controller is not the initial controller, but I found a fix (at least for my simple case), and that was to remove the presented view controller's view from its superview before calling presentViewController. I've edited my answer; I added one line to the implementation of viewFinishedAnimating: in InitialViewController.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works perfectly now! This issue is indeed very strange.